# Argument Access in Advice

Tags: advice

In the [documentation](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_220.html), two ways are suggested for accessing arguments in an advice: by the name of the argument in the original function and by using special functions. I cannot get the second way to work. Here is my attempt:

```
(defun my-insert-for-yank(orig-fun &rest args)
  (insert (ad-get-arg 1)))

(advice-add 'insert-for-yank :around #'my-insert-for-yank)
```

When I run `(insert-for-yank "aa bb")`, I get a message about `ad-get-arg` being a `void` function.

What am I missing?

Comment: An up-to-date link: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html, also accessible from your Emacs with `<f1> i d m elisp g advising functions`

Answer (score 4):

You're reading the doc for Emacs-21's advice (i.e. `defadvice`) and use it with Emacs-25's advice (i.e. `advice-add`).

All th `ad-*` thingies are specific to `defadvice`.  So your example code should be written using "normal" Elisp functionality, such as:

```
(defun my-insert-for-yank (_orig-fun &rest args)
  (insert (nth 0 args)))
```

or

```
(defun my-insert-for-yank (_orig-fun string)
  (insert string))
```

Comment: I want to accept the answer, but for some reason the "V" for doing that does not appear.